# Get variables from a href php

Tags: php, variables, get, href

I have:

```
  <a href="settings.php?yeah=<?php echo $yeah;?> & word=<? echo $word;?">Settings</a>
```

and in settings php:

```
  <? echo $_GET['yeah'];
     echo $_GET['word'];
  ?>
```

The problem is that it is working only for yeah.

Comment: Get rid of the space around your ampersand (`&`)

Comment: And use `&amp;` not &

Comment: & is legal character here.

Comment: @szpal: No, it is not for valid markup.

Comment: can you show me any reference?

Comment: @szpal: It will work when clicked, however, try it in http://validator.w3.org or see http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the spaces between the variables in href :

```
 <a href="settings.php?yeah=<?php echo $yeah;?>&amp;word=<?php echo $word;?"> Settings </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space from it

```
<a href="settings.php?yeah=<?php echo $yeah;?>&amp;word=<?php echo $word;?">Settings</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the extra spaces around the '&' sign, like this:

```
<a href="settings.php?yeah=<?php echo $yeah;?>&word=<? echo $word;?">Settings</a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a href="settings.php?yeah=<?php echo $yeah;?>&word=<?php echo $word;?">Settings</a>
```

remove spaces and I'm strongly recommending use `<?php` not just `<?`